# Bundling Bootstrap 4 - Bootstrap tooltips require Tether

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that's being built with Bootstrap 4. In this app, I have a Bower file, has the following:

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "tether": "1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "v4.0.0-alpha.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am trying to bundle these files with several custom JavaScript files. In an attempt to do this, I have the following Gulp task:

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('bundleJs', function() {
  var jsFiles = [
    './bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    './bower_components/tether/dist/tether.min.js',
    './bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    './public/core.js',
    './public/utils.js'
  ];

  return gulp.src(jsFiles)
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
  ;
});
```

Then, in my web page, I'm referencing the file like this:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

My web page loads and I can see that bundle.js has successfully loaded. However, in the console window, I see the following error:

*Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether*

I believe that this is why my hamburger menu no longer works on mobile. My question is, is there a way to bundle these files together? Or, do I need to load each individually?

Comment: Is the **Tether** variable defined after the loading of your bundle ?

Comment: The contents of the tether.min.js file have been copied into bundle.js. The contents appear before the Bootstrap.min.js file's contents.

Comment: Try to use the latest bootstrap `4.0.0-alpha.6` instead of alpha 5. And also the latest Tether version `1.4`. If I use alpha5 my tooltip doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your project.

The URL pointing to the tether JS file in you gulp file seems to be incorrect.

It should be:

```
'./bower_components/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js',
```

instead of:

```
'./bower_components/tether/dist/tether.min.js',
```